# You need to call create() at least once to create the singleton

Tags: android, react-native, singleton

I'm working on Geolocation Background Task, when I'll be run the app is everything ok, but when close or restart the app the message is showing.

I´m actually using this package for background geolocation
https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

And OneSignal SDK for react native too.

> ```
>     OS: Windows 10
>     CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
>     Memory: 3.86 GB / 11.88 GB   Binaries:
>     Node: 10.16.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
>     Yarn: 1.17.3 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
>     npm: 6.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD   SDKs:
>     Android SDK:
>       API Levels: 19, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
>       Build Tools: 26.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.1
>       System Images: android-23 | Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-23 |
> Google APIs  Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom,
> android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86
> Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google
> Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64  
> IDEs:
>     Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203   npmPackages:
>     react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
>     react-native: ^0.60.5 => 0.60.6
> ```

I´m uninstalling both, OneSignal and background geolocation - still
showing the message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It may be better to paste the (error?) message into the question body (block quote welcome).